# suggestion on saving the day hours values to db

Tags: java, jpa

I am working with the one timesheet project. There we need to save the
week day values (from Monday to sunday) to the database. The composite primary keys are 
expected userid,taskid and date. A user can enter hours for one or more than
one task on One particular day. So when a user enters the values, he selects taskid and hours
of a day. What would be the best approach to design the table?
1. should it have 10 columns(userid,taskid,date and hours on from monday to Sunday) or
2. should it have only 4 column(userid,taskid,date and hour)?

what I have thought is to go with the second approach since I need to generate report on weekly and by considering
if the requirement comes to take by day by day report, second option would be nice.

I need a good suggestion on how to save the wee values.

Comment: Why not userid taskid start and end? And always work in utc.

Comment: how to give end date? user enter ona day value. for example Monday he puts 5 hours on one task and another 5 hours on another task. The date would store and hours. So two rows of date would be stored btw, what is meant by utc ?